# How to count amount of views in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-view

Is there a way for Android Studio to show how many views that are present within an XML layout? As we all know, layouts should contain <=80 views hence any more than that then this warning appears therefore it would be very helpful to be told the amount.

> LayoutName.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance

```
public class FragmentApple extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentApple () {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apple,container,false);

        int num = FragmentApple.getChildCount(); Log.d("Number of views in layout: ", "" + num);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
layout.getChildCount();
```

**UPDATE**

after what we discussed in the comments, this is what you should do within your code:

```
public class FragmentApple extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public FragmentApple () {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apple,container,false);



    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
super.onStart()
RelativeLayout (or Linear as in your xml) rl = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewbyId(R.id.your_layout_id)

int num = rl.getChildCount();
 Log.d("Number of views in layout: ", "" + num);
}

    }
```

Comment: I don't want to show the number of views on the emulator/device. I only want the application (Android Studio) to tell me itself.

Comment: ok you can write like this:

int num = layout.getChildCount();
Log.d("Number of views in layout: ", "" + num);

this will print the number in your logcat

Comment: Where does this need to be typed in?

Comment: What do I need to replace `layout` with?

Comment: your layout name that you want to know how many views inside of it. after you inflate it with an XML ofcourse.

Comment: I did that but it says **Cannot resolve method 'getChildCount()'**.

Comment: Code can see seen above

Comment: your code should be like the following:
int num = v.getChildCount();

Comment: Error is still there. I'll still accept your answer anyway.

Comment: I know how to solve your error, i will edit my answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

for new comers to this question, you could use the view hierarchy from android studio's android device monitor:

open the app from your device or an emulator, and browse to the view that you want to inspect

1- from the Studio's Menu bar open

```
 tools -> Android -> Android device monitor
```

2- from Android device monitor Menu bar open

```
 window -> open perspective -> Hierarchy view
```

it may load for some time.

if you want to learn more: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html